# how to create virtual hosts on ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

I want to create virtual hosts on ubuntu. I am using ubuntu and apache server.

For example I have two files like this:

```
/var/www/project1/index.php
/var/www/project2/index.php
```

I want that when I use **project1.dev** in browser then it should point **/var/www/project1/index.php**

And

If I use **project2.dev** in browser then it should point **/var/www/project2/index.php**

I have tried some articles but there are lot of information and I am unable to run it. I am new to ubuntu, Can someone tell me exact points and commands?

Thanks

Comment: i always refresh my memory on this topic from this article http://www.debuntu.org/2006/02/22/7-virtual-hosting-using-apache-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define your virtual hosts by creating files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. For example:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/project1.dev
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName project1.dev
        ServerAlias www.project1.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project1.dev/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

You can then enable them by running `sudo a2ensite virtualhostname`. For example, `a2ensite project1.dev`. Then reload apache by running with `sudo service apache2 reload`.

You will also need to add an entry to `/etc/hosts` so that you can access them using fake domain names in your browser. For example:

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1    project1.dev
```

Is that helpful or do you need some more info?

Comment: and don't forget to reload apache after `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`

Comment: Ah, good catch!